# Login form is not directing to dashboard page after user logs in

Tags: laravel

I am trying to redirect logged in users to the main dashboard view, that I've titled as "xwelcome.blade.php" temporarily.

I've attached my routes:

```
Route::get('xwelcome', [CustomAuthController::class, 'xwelcome']); 

Route::get('login', [CustomAuthController::class, 'index'])->name('login');

Route::post('custom-login', [CustomAuthController::class, 'customLogin'])->name('login.custom'); 

Route::get('registration', [CustomAuthController::class, 'registration'])->name('register-user');

Route::post('custom-registration', [CustomAuthController::class, 'customRegistration'])->name('register.custom'); 

Route::get('logout', [CustomAuthController::class, 'logOut'])->name('logout');
```

This is my CustomAuthController:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Hash;
use Session;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class CustomAuthController extends Controller

{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }  
      
    public function customLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
   
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->intended('xwelcome')
                        ->withSuccess('Signed in');
        }
  
        return redirect("login")->withSuccess('Login details are not valid');
    }

    public function registration()
    {
        return view('auth.registration');
    }
      
    public function customRegistration(Request $request)
    {  
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);
           
        $data = $request->all();
        $check = $this->create($data);
         
        return redirect("xwelcome")->withSuccess('You have signed-in');
    }

    public function create(array $data)
    {
      return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
      ]);
    }    
    
    public function dashboard()
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            return view('xwelcome');
        }
  
        return redirect("login")->withSuccess('You are not allowed to access');
    }
    
    public function logOut() {
        Session::flush();
        Auth::logout();
  
        return Redirect('login');
    }
}
```

Login button:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('login.custom') }}">
                        @csrf
                      <div class="mt-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-control-label">Email address</label>
                        <div class="input-group input-group-merge">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                          </div>
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="input-email" placeholder="name@example.com">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group mb-4">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                          <div>
                            <label class="form-control-label">Password</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="mb-2">
                            <a href="#!" class="small text-muted text-underline--dashed border-primary">Lost password?</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group input-group-merge">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                          </div>
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="input-password" placeholder="Password">
                          <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                              <a href="#" data-toggle="password-text" data-target="#input-password">
                                <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                              </a>
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-icon rounded-pill">
                         <span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i></span>
                        Sign In
                        </button></div>
                    </form>
```

After I fill in my test account details, and press the button, I see this in my address bar

```
https://example.com/login?_token=0GddRaD453thhRFL7KWgEQ5DnZ3q7B4rL5gaajuM
```

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the input fields in your form!.

Have you tried to display the errors after validating the form?.

I think that you are redirected back to :

> https://example.com/login?_token=0GddRaD453thhRFL7KWgEQ5DnZ3q7B4rL5gaajuM

because you are missing the input:email and input:password, what your are seeing is only the csrf token that laravel generates.

Comment: Hi Oussama, I made the edits you suggested and am now being redirected back to the /login page. I have uploaded the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

i Think issue is on button . try this out

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('login.custom') }}">
                        @csrf
                      <div class="mt-4">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-icon rounded-pill">
                        
          <span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i></span>
                        Sign In
                        </button></div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: That has not fixed the issue mate, still getting the login? error.

Comment: can you share the screenshot of exact error you getting

Answer (score 0):

you are missing name attribute in your input field. the code should look like

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('login.custom') }}">
                    @csrf
                  <div class="mt-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label">Email address</label>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-merge">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                      </div>
                      <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="input-email" placeholder="name@example.com">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group mb-4">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                      <div>
                        <label class="form-control-label">Password</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="mb-2">
                        <a href="#!" class="small text-muted text-underline--dashed border-primary">Lost password?</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-merge">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                      </div>
                      <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="input-password" placeholder="Password">
                      <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                          <a href="#" data-toggle="password-text" data-target="#input-password">
                            <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                          </a>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-icon rounded-pill">
                     <span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i></span>
                    Sign In
                    </button></div>
                </form>
```